# Adding a new english sentence to wordpress localisation translation

Tags: php, wordpress

I am starting out wordpress plugin development trying to extend an existing plugin.

This plugin has a languages folder, with a .po and .mo file for french and indian. There are references in the plugin code like :

```
<?php _e("Start Date", "pluginxyz"); ?>
```

I want to add :

```
<?php _e("Length of Class Block", "pluginxyz"); ?>
```

I am not entirely sure what I need to do in order to make this work. My plugin page throws the error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS http://127.0.0.1:8080/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=classes
```

Which i assume is because the "Length of Class Block" text is not found in a file somewhere which the e() is looking for. I have installed a plugin to help with localisation : https://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/ and I have rescanned the 2 .po files using this tool but I have no idea where or how to add "Length of Class Block" as an english statement to my plugin!

Can somebody please explain and help!

Answer (score 1):

For further development, you could either

1 Parse the PO-file for the english definitions, and generate a PO-file from the data, or

2: "Translate" the code-source into a separate en_US.po. By uting this method, the plugin is more open for further development by developers with another native language.

Edit: If you ar looking for a tool to edit the PO/MO-files, I really recommend POEdit, I use it all the time when I need to translate something to Norwegian.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out. The long answer was to install and setup grunt-pot which would scan my project for references in PHP to _e() calls etc and extract them into a POT file. This pot file could then be used to generate .po files which are the translated versions of the text, and then compile that into a binary .mo file.

I then figured out another thing - and that is, if _e() cannot find the reference in the localisation it just continues to spit out that string anyway - so for now, that what I shall do and in the future I can go along and use grunt-pot to create a pot file to create a distributable po and mo file for my users to have a localised plugin.